# How can i divide, multiply and get the mod of two variables within a case command?

Tags: shell, math

I have my plus and minus working fine, but I cant seem to be able to get the divide, multiply or mod of two input variables, any ideas?

```
  case $oper in  
  + ) result=$(( $fact1 + $fact2 ));;
  - ) result=$(( $fact1 - $fact2 ));;
  / ) result=$(( $fact1 / $fact2 ));;
  x ) result=$(( $fact1 * $fact2 ));;
  X ) result=$(( $fact1 * $fact2 ));;
  mod ) result=$(( $fact1  % $fact2 ))
  * ) echo
     echo "Invalid operation: $oper"
     echo
     exit 1;;
  esac
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: what do you mean, this is a case statement that executes an arithmetic equation based on what symbol you give it, example, since the program name is "do_math", the command would be   ./do_math 1 + 1. which would give the answer of two variable (fact1 and fact2), which in this case were both "1".

Comment: There are a number of languages that have `case` statements. You hadn't specified that this was intended as a command line invocation.

Comment: Sorry, it must have cut that off the top.

Comment: I was able to get everything working except the mod, that one is still not working well, is this the correct format?

       `mod ) result=$(( $fact1  % $fact2 ));;`

Answer (score 1):

Your difficulty is caused by the omitted `;;` on the `mod` line. Instead, that line should read:

```
  mod ) result=$(( $fact1  % $fact2 ));;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10170383)

Comment: @Chris I appreciate that this is a brief answer, but it is both complete and correct. Nevertheless, I can amplify.